# Why Go queries /etc/hosts twice in a name resolution?

Tags: go, dns

Recently I am reading source code of `net` package of Go. When I was diving into the name resolution part, it looked like Go had queried `/etc/hosts` twice:

First in `net/dnsclient_unix.go`[goLookupHostOrder](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/9e277f7d554455e16ba3762541c53e9bfc1d8188/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go#L518-L524):

```
func (r *Resolver) goLookupHostOrder(ctx context.Context, name string, order hostLookupOrder) (addrs []string, err error) {
    if order == hostLookupFilesDNS || order == hostLookupFiles {
        // Use entries from /etc/hosts if they match.
        addrs = lookupStaticHost(name)
        if len(addrs) > 0 || order == hostLookupFiles {
            return
        }   
    }   
    ips, _, err := r.goLookupIPCNAMEOrder(ctx, name, order)
```

Then in [goLookupIPCNAMEOrder](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/9e277f7d554455e16ba3762541c53e9bfc1d8188/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go#L558-L563):

```
func (r *Resolver) goLookupIPCNAMEOrder(ctx context.Context, name string, order hostLookupOrder) (addrs []IPAddr, cname dnsmessage.Name, err error) {
    if order == hostLookupFilesDNS || order == hostLookupFiles {
        // goLookupIPFiles invokes lookupStaticHost internally.
        addrs = goLookupIPFiles(name)
        if len(addrs) > 0 || order == hostLookupFiles {
            return addrs, dnsmessage.Name{}, nil
        } 
    }
```

So is this a bug? Or It does have some reason but not documented?

Comment: There is a different line in the first if statement. Look at `addrs = lookupStaticHost(name)` vs `addrs = goLookupIPFiles(name)`

Comment: goLookupIPFiles invokes lookupStaticHost, it only adds some format converting stuff.